# Google Geocoding - function does not work when submit address by key "ENTER"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am facing a problem is that:
When I typed address and click "Enter" in keyboard, the page would be reloaded. The progress would stop before "google.maps.Geocoder().geocode()" automatically.
It looks like the key "Enter" is causing a post back and resetting the map before the geocoder callback function is finished.

"store-search-street" is my textFiled, if I wrote related method in below:

```
   $('#store-search-street').keyup(function(e){
       storeLocator.updateMap();
       storeLocator.fire('sl:store-locator-search')
       return false;
    });
```

Then when I copy the address to textfield, it can execute the geocode() and everything is fine. But there is no key "Enter" involve in it.

When I changed the code to below to make "click ENTER to submit address"

```
 $('#store-search-street').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
       storeLocator.updateMap();
       storeLocator.fire('sl:store-locator-search')
       return false; }
    });
```

the geocode() deose not work.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: try `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using a form to get the details.

Normally a form will post information to a website, not just fire off a script without going anywhere.

You need to catch that form submission (the enter keypress) and supress it so your script runs instead.

```
<form id="postcodeEntry" method="post" action="/" onsubmit="some_javascript_function";return false;">
```

Throw in an 'onsubmit' to catch the form submission.